# How to manage dependencies with Rollup.js?

Tags: npm-install, package.json, rollupjs

I have created a package using Rollup.js. (myRollupPackage)

I would like to specify the other packages that I require in my main application here.

After adding the myRollupPackage package to my main application and running the npm install command, I would like the dependencies that I specified in my package to be installed in my main application.

**my package**

```
package.json (myRollupPackage)
{
  "name": "myRollupPackage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
...
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.3",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
  }

...
}
```

**my application**

```
package.json (Main App)
{
  "name": "mainApp",
  "version": "2.0.0",
...
"dependencies": {
    "myRollupPackage": "1.0.0"
  }

...
}
```

`mainApp -> npm install`

```
mainApp\node_modules ->
...
myRollupPackage
@material-ui/core
@mui/icons-material
@mui/material
jspdf
....
```

How to manage dependencies with Rollup.js?